# Bash Script to Open a Shell, Run a Command in the Shell, & Keep Shell Running

Tags: bash, automation, kubectl

I'm trying to automate these steps using a bash script

1. Run a command to access the shell of a program (bash shell of a Kubernetes pod)

   ```
   kubectl exec --stdin --tty hello-node-7567d9fdc9-zvz55 -- bash
   ```
2. In this shell, run a second command (eg. `python`)

   ```
   root@hello-node-7567d9fdc9-zvz55:/# python

   Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 15:17:50) 
   [Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
   >>>
   ```
3. Keep the shell **open/running in the foreground** (so more commands can immediately be entered by a user into the python shell started in step 2)

I'm able to do the first step described above using the script below. How do we do the second and third step?

```
#! /bin/bash
bash -c 'kubectl exec --stdin --tty hello-node-7567d9fdc9-zvz55 -- bash'
```

Comment: you need to write a `pexpect` script

Comment: Or use `python -c 'print("hello from python"); print ("hi")'` for supplying multiple python commands

Comment: You can try to [run individual commands in a pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/#running-individual-commands-in-a-container), also can be useful to check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64426653/16344509).

Comment: You can replace `bash -c 'kubectl …'` with just `kubectl …`: there’s absolutely no reason to spawn *yet another* shell process inside your shell script.

Answer (score 0):

For step 2 you can use the `nohup` command to run a process and even if the user logs off the process does not get killed. Afterwards the shell is kept running for you to perform step 3

Comment: I'll like the bash script to run steps 1-3 and end up with the python shell open in the foreground. I think `nohup` keeps the process running but keeps it in the background

Comment: Ok so once you have the interactive Bash session which is step 1 you can start Python. If Python is not installed, you can install Python as normal, as if you had a normal Linux server and you have logged in.